# MDI Document taskbar thumbnails with no decorations

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, windows-7

Is it possible to remove the close window decoration from an mdi document taskbar flyout window? That is, remove the red "x" to prevent the user from closing the document via the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your window:

```
CMenu* pSysMenu = this->GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
pSysMenu->RemoveMenu(SC_CLOSE,MF_BYCOMMMAND);
```